# In Magento When i click Ship, the order status should be processing

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, shipping, order-status

In Magento When i click Ship, the order status should be processing.
When i click invoice the status should be payment pending.
How do i do that? Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

```
system > order stauses
```

and change the state you want to assign on status.